# SystemUI.apk is not in /system/app

Tags: adb, system

I tried to pull SystemUI.apk on my Samsung Android Pie/OneUI and it seems like it's either in some other directory than /system/app or has been renamed. I tried to pull this through adb. Tried different cases for it but didn't work. To anyone curious, I want to modify me status bar icons. Does someone know where it might be located?

Comment: Is your device rooted? Because modifying a system app requires root permissions.

Comment: No it's not. I didn't know it won't work without rooting. The guide I was using didn't make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Android 4.4, all privileged system apps including SystemUI have been moved to `/system/priv-app`.

Comment: P.S. You could've figured this out on your own with a simple `find` command... Also, the fact you're looking for it under the old path likely means you're following a very old guide which might not work now either.

Comment: Yea I think the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To find its location, you can use this `adb` command:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f | grep systemui
```